# What is the difference between a UIHandler and a Handler

Tags: android

I want to show numbers from 1 to 100 in sequel order in the TextView and to wait 1 second after printing each number. I also want to implement it using Android services.
I don't know the difference between UIHandler and Handler. When I google about this issue, all I am getting is the difference between handler and a thread.
Please help me out of this,
Thanks in advance

```
private static final int SHOW_MESSAGE = 1;
private static final int m_cdelay = 1000;
private UIHandler m_cUIHandler;
public int m_cI= 0;
TextView m_cTextShow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    m_cTextShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    for(m_cI=1; m_cI <= 100; m_cI++){
       //m_cUIHandler = new UIHandler();
       //m_cUIHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SHOW_MESSAGE, 1000);
       showMessage(m_cI);
    }
}

private void showMessage(int m_cI2) {
    for(m_cI=1; m_cI <= 100; m_cI++){
         m_cTextShow.setText(""+m_cI);
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  try {
                        Thread.sleep(m_cdelay);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }}).start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     startService(new Intent(this, NumberService.class));
}

public final class UIHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message pObjMessage) {
        switch(pObjMessage.what) {
            case SHOW_MESSAGE:
                m_cTextShow.setText(""+m_cI);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your problem? as it is stated in your question you are building a class called "UIHandler" and then you are asking us what is the difference. There actually is no difference between a UIHandler and a Handler. The UIHandler handles actions on the UI the Handler does the same anywhere.

Comment: actually I am new to android and as i now know the difference between them and i also would like to know if there is any alternative over thread in my code as it is not making a delay of 1 second.

Comment: sure, don't use Thread, just use a Handler.postDelayed()

Comment: thankyou so much @pskink .. I would much prefer if  a small example could be given on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually rewrite your code like that to make it probably work.
Pls test it and respond.

```
public void showMessage(int number){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
           //Write your number onto the screen 
        }
    });
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Blablabla...
    for(m_cI=1; m_cI <= 100; m_cI++){
       //m_cUIHandler = new UIHandler();
       //m_cUIHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SHOW_MESSAGE, 1000);
       showMessage(m_cI);
       Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```